# How do you correctly construct and use a buffer for a socket?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm, definitelytyped

I'm trying to convert a piece of code to TypeScript and I've run into an issue with a `Buffer` that I use with a UDP socket.

The code I'm working with looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts" />
import dgram = require( "dgram" );

var udpServer:dgram.Socket = dgram.createSocket( "udp4" );

var message = new Buffer( "foo" );
udpServer.send( message, 0, message.length, 1337, "255.255.255.255" );
```

WebStorm complains about `message` with the error `Argument type Buffer is not assignable to argument type NodeBuffer`.

I understand that this is due to the fact that `Socket.send()` requires a `NodeBuffer` as the first argument and I'm supplying a `Buffer`. But how can I overcome this?

I can't use `NodeBuffer` as the type of `message`, that just leads to different errors.

```
var message:NodeBuffer = new Buffer( "foo" );
```

Will lead to `Initializer type Buffer is not assignable to variable type NodeBuffer`

```
var message:NodeBuffer = new NodeBuffer( "foo" );
```

Will lead to `Argument types do not match parameters`.

This is confusing me due to the examples given at http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html which worked for me in plain JavaScript.

So, how do I properly construct a buffer that I can send over my UDP socket?

Comment: Is your `node.d.ts` fully up-to-date? It should have something like these lines https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1fd738c346a7a49d24c7817e4289bf1a78f2ebbb/node/node.d.ts#L54-62 defining that `new Buffer` returns a `NodeBuffer`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes, I cloned it yesterday directly from GitHub. I saw that declaration as well and it confused me even more in regards to the complaint in the IDE.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I guess it's a bug in WebStorm as the code *compiles* just fine. I reported it as [WEB-10488](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10488).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by having the **Node.js v0.8.16 Core Modules** library enabled in the JavaScript settings of WebStorm.

This confused WebStorm in regards to which type the `Buffer` actually is. Disabling the library would resolve the error hint.

Sadly, that isn't really an option for us as the project uses both Node.js with JavaScript *and* TypeScript code. But at least I now know what the problem is.